Show that $H_n$ represents a bilinear form
Recently, I had a linear algebra quiz which included the following extra problem (which I didn't have enough time to solve):
For all $n\geq 1$, let $H_n\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the matrix whose entry $(i,j)$ is $1/(i+j-1)$. Let $V$ be the space of polynomials of degree strictly less than $n$, and $f$ the bilinear form over $V$ given by $f(p,q)=\int_{0}^{1} pq$. Show thay $H_n$ is the matrix of $f$ with respect to some basis of $V$.

Let $B=\{ v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}=\{1,x,...,x^{n-1}\}$ be a basis of $V$.
Clearly, $v_k=x^{k-1}$ for all $k\geq 1$. Let's denote  $A:=[f]_B$.
Now, in order to show that $A=H_n$, I need to show that these two matrices have the same corresponding entries.
The first approach that came to my mind was to compute each entry of both matrices and see thy they are equal: For example, $$f(v_1,v_1):=a_{11}=1=h_{11},$$ $$f(v_1,v_2):=a_{12}= 1/2=h_{12},$$ and so on. But this is a "tedious" process.
So, the second approach that came to my mind is to show that an arbitrary entry of $A$ has the same form as an arbitrary entry of $H_n$.
Now the $(i,j)$ entry of $A$ is given by $$f(v_i,v_j)=\int_{0}^{1} x^{i-1}x^{j-1} dx=\frac{1}{j+i-1}.$$
Thus, $H_n$ is clearly a matrix representation of $f$ with respect to $B$.
My question is: Is the second approach enough to show what the exercise demands? Is it correct?

In my opinion, I think it is correct.
